# Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError [in thread "Worker-xx: Updating Maven Project"

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

getting this error in 1st line of pom.xml

> Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError [in thread "Worker-xx: Updating Maven Project"]

Cant understand what is wrong.

I have tried the following steps -> 'Preferences > Maven > Annotation Processing > Do not automatically configure/execute annotation processing from pom.xml' but this did not work for me. what else can be done?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.